# Reducing an array of object in to one object and group some commom information in to an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

What i mean is that I have an array of object like below,

```
connectionInfo: any = [
    {
      "deviceName": "transponder1",
      "ports": 4,
      "rowNo": 1,
      "columnNo": 1,
      "posX": 2060.5,
      "posY": 200,
      "portInfo": {
        "portNumber": "1",
        "x": "2260.5",
        "y": "261.6666666666667"
      }
    },
    {
      "deviceName": "transponder1",
      "ports": 4,
      "rowNo": 1,
      "columnNo": 1,
      "posX": 2060.5,
      "posY": 200,
      "portInfo": {
        "portNumber": "2",
        "x": "2260.5",
        "y": "395"
      }
    },
    {
      "deviceName": "transponder1",
      "ports": 4,
      "rowNo": 1,
      "columnNo": 1,
      "posX": 2060.5,
      "posY": 200,
      "portInfo": {
        "portNumber": "3",
        "x": "2260.5",
        "y": "528.3333333333334"
      }
    }
];
```

How i want the output to be is below here,

```
{
  "deviceName": "transponder1",
  "ports": 4,
  "rowNo": 1,
  "columnNo": 1,
  "posX": 2060.5,
  "posY": 200,
  "portInfo": {
    "portNumber": "1",
    "x": "2260.5",
    "y": "261.6666666666667"
  },
  "allPortsInfo": [
    {
      "portNumber": "1",
      "x": "2260.5",
      "y": "261.6666666666667"
    },
    {
      "portNumber": "2",
      "x": "2260.5",
      "y": "395"
    },
    {
      "portNumber": "3",
      "x": "2260.5",
      "y": "528.3333333333334"
    },
    {
      "portNumber": "4",
      "x": "2260.5",
      "y": "528.3333333333334"
    }
  ]
}
```

What i tried is below here,
const cInfo = this.connectionInfo.reduce((acc, value) => acc.concat(value.portInfo),[]);

With the above approach my output is ,

```
[
  {
    "portNumber": "1",
    "x": "2260.5",
    "y": "261.6666666666667"
  },
  {
    "portNumber": "2",
    "x": "2260.5",
    "y": "395"
  },
  {
    "portNumber": "3",
    "x": "2260.5",
    "y": "528.3333333333334"
  },
  {
    "portNumber": "4",
    "x": "2260.5",
    "y": "528.3333333333334"
  }
]
```

I have used reduce and gathered all the portInfo in to an array of all portInfo
but i just dont know if i could make expected output within the reduce loop.

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbalc9?file=src/app/app.component.ts) on stackblitz

Comment: what is the common part of the data? do you have different data with eg `"transponder2"`?

Comment: yes. I have array of transponders.

Comment: do you need redunant `portInfo` in the grouped data?

Comment: It cannot be redundant data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an already grouped array, you could take the first element as object and add a new property by mapping only the `portInfo` property.

```js
var data = [[{ deviceName: "transponder1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 1, posX: 2060.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "1", x: "2260.5", y: "261.6666666666667" } }, { deviceName: "transponder1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 1, posX: 2060.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "2", x: "2260.5", y: "395" } }, { deviceName: "transponder1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 1, posX: 2060.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "3", x: "2260.5", y: "528.3333333333334" } }], [{ deviceName: "amplifier1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 2, posX: 2860.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "1", x: "3060.5", y: "261.6666666666667" } }, { deviceName: "amplifier1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 2, posX: 2860.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "2", x: "3060.5", y: "395" } }, { deviceName: "amplifier1", ports: 3, rowNo: 1, columnNo: 2, posX: 2860.5, posY: 200, portInfo: { portNumber: "3", x: "3060.5", y: "528.3333333333334" } }]],
    result = data.map(array => ({
        ...array[0],
        allPortsInfo: array.map(({ portInfo }) => portInfo)
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: really is just `cInfo = {...this.connectionInfo[0],allPortInfo:this.connectionInfo.map(i=>i.portInfo)}`the `...` is the spread operator. when we want create an object with all the properties of another and others properties we use `{...myBobject,prop1:value1,prop2:value2}`, see https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html. When we has an array of object `[{prop1:value1,prop2:value2},{prop1:value1,prop2:value2},...]` we use map to get an array with one propertie `myArray.map(x=>x.propertie}` (and return [value1,value1].